# I have a lot of packages marked as manually installed. What the cons of this?

Tags: debian, apt

In one of my old inherited servers, I execute

```
 apt-mark showmanual
```

And I get a list of near 100 entries.

> adduser
> apache2
> apt
> apt-listchanges
> apt-utils
> aptitude
> aptitude-common
> at
> base-files
> base-passwd
> bash
> bash-completion
> bc
> bind9-dnsutils
> bind9-host
> bsd-mailx
> bsdextrautils
> bsdutils
> busybox
> bzip2
> coreutils
> cpio
> cpp
> cron
> curl
> dash
> dbus
> dc
> debconf
> debconf-i18n
> debian-archive-keyring
> debian-faq
> debianutils
> diffutils
> discover
> dmsetup
> dnsutils
> doc-debian
> dpkg
> e2fslibs
> e2fsprogs
> fail2ban
> file
> findutils
> g++
> gcc
> gcc-4.8-base
> gcc-4.9-base
> gettext-base
> gnupg
> gpgv
> grep
> groff-base
> gzip
> host
> hostname
> htop
> ifupdown
> inetutils-telnet
> info
> init
> init-system-helpers
> initscripts
> insserv
> install-info
> installation-report
> iotop
> iproute2
> iptables
> iputils-ping
> isc-dhcp-client
> isc-dhcp-common
> krb5-locales
> less
> libacl1
> libapt-inst1.5
> libapt-pkg4.12
> libasan6
> libattr1
> libaudit-common
> libaudit1
> libblkid1
> libboost-iostreams1.55.0
> libbz2-1.0
> libc-bin
> libc6
> libcap2
> libcap2-bin
> libclass-isa-perl
> libcomerr2
> libcryptsetup4
> libdb5.3
> libdebconfclient0
> libdevmapper1.02.1
> libdns-export100
> libestr0
> libffi-dev
> libffi6
> libgcc1
> libgcrypt20
> libgd3
> libgdbm3
> libgmp10
> libgnutls-deb0-28
> libgnutls-openssl27
> libgpg-error0
> libhogweed2
> libicu52
> libidn11
> libirs-export91
> libisc-export95
> libisccfg-export90
> libjson-c2
> libkmod2
> liblocale-gettext-perl
> liblockfile-bin
> liblogging-stdlog0
> liblognorm1
> liblzma5
> libmnl0
> libmount1
> libncurses5
> libncursesw5
> libnetfilter-acct1
> libnettle4
> libnewt0.52
> libnfnetlink0
> libp11-kit0
> libpam-modules
> libpam-modules-bin
> libpam-runtime
> libpam0g
> libpcre3
> libpipeline1
> libpng12-0
> libpopt0
> libprocps3
> libpsl0
> libreadline6
> libselinux1
> libsemanage-common
> libsepol1
> libslang2
> libsmartcols1
> libsnmp-base
> libss2
> libssl-dev
> libssl1.0.0
> libstdc++6
> libswitch-perl
> libsystemd0
> libtasn1-6
> libtext-charwidth-perl
> libtext-iconv-perl
> libtext-wrapi18n-perl
> libtinfo5
> libudev1
> liburi-perl
> libusb-0.1-4
> libustr-1.0-1
> libuuid1
> libxtables10
> locales
> login
> logrotate
> lsb-base
> lsb-release
> lsof
> m4
> man-db
> manpages
> mariadb-client
> mariadb-server
> mawk
> mime-support
> mlocate
> mount
> mtr-tiny
> multiarch-support
> mysql-client
> mysql-common
> nano
> ncal
> ncpa
> ncurses-base
> ncurses-bin
> ncurses-term
> net-tools
> netbase
> netcat-traditional
> nfacct
> nfs-common
> ntp
> ntpdate
> openssh-client
> openssh-server
> openssh-sftp-server
> openssl
> p7zip-full
> passwd
> patch
> perl
> perl-base
> php-xml
> php5
> php5-gd
> php5-mysql
> postfix
> postfix-sqlite
> procmail
> procps
> python2.7
> python3-debian
> python3-httplib2
> readline-common
> reportbug
> rpcbind
> rsync
> rsyslog
> screen
> sed
> sensible-utils
> snapd
> startpar
> sudo
> sysstat
> systemd
> systemd-sysv
> sysv-rc
> sysvinit-utils
> tar
> task-english
> task-ssh-server
> tasksel
> tasksel-data
> texinfo
> time
> tnftp
> traceroute
> tzdata
> ucf
> udev
> ufw
> unzip
> util-linux
> vim
> vim-common
> virtualenv
> w3m
> wamerican
> wget
> whiptail
> whois
> xz-utils
> zip
> zlib1g

Are there any potential issues in the future if I have one package (or a large number of packages in my case) marked as manually installed?

Should I mark them as automatically installed (and attempt to remove them later using autoremove)?

Actually it's a Debian 12 Bookworm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only consequence of a package being marked as manually installed is that it won’t be removed by `apt autoremove`. The set of packages marked as manually installed should reflect the packages which are needed on your server; for example, if you need the Apache web server, then `apache2` should be marked as manually installed.

You can automatically reduce the set of packages marked as manually installed by running

```
apt-mark minimize-manual
```

(as root).

See also [Why are many of my packages marked as manually installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/703820/86440)

Comment: I use Ubuntu and Debian for more than 15 years, and I never see this command and the `apt-mark` tool before. It's so useful! `apt-mark showmanual` shows the packages that are marked as manually installed, I had several base packages in that list, which is weird, but `apt-mark auto …` fixes this.